# Which hands do not consist of sets and a pair?

Tags: mahjong

I know of only two hands that do not consist of 4 sets and a pair in riichi mahjong: Seven Pairs, and Thirteen Orphans. Are there more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on this [source](http://www.msoworld.com/mindzine/news/orient/mah_jong/overview_special.html) I would say that those are the only ones.

Answer (score 1):

In some variants you have hands like Knitting (seven cross-suit pairs), Thirteen Grades of Imperial Treasure, and the Wriggling Snake.

[This page](http://w1.1332.telia.com/~u133200063/hands.htm) matches the rulebook I learned from. It describes several others such as Windy Chows, Dragonfly, Heavenly Twins (a special case of All Pairs), Run Pung & Pair, and Red Lantern.

I believe most of these should apply to riichi mahjong as well.

Answer (score 1):

[This source](http://www.ofb.net/~whuang/ugcs/gp/mahjong/mahjong.html) explicitly states that 13O and 7P are the only exceptions in Riichi.

> A Winning hand is, except for two
>   exceptions, composed of four MELDS
>   (mentsu [面子]) and a PAIR (jantoo,
>   [雀頭]). The two exceptions are the
>   SEVEN PAIRS (chiitoitsu [七対子]) hands
>   (covered in a later section) and the
>   THIRTEEN ENDS (kokushimusoo [国士無双])
>   hands (covered later in the special
>   hands section)